# Grabbing 190k rows from MySQL using PHP, blank page? Memory or buffer?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to grab all data from a table, to calculate some stats.

There is currently 190.000 rows and counting, and I am selecting only the columns necessary.

Using Kohana Query Builder, when I do execute()->count() `(counts the rows only)` on the MySQL query, it works fine and returns the number 190.000

When i try to fetch the data, by doing `execute()->as_array()`, it dies - it shows a blank page.

I tried researching to determine if it was a MySQL database limit/buffer limit, or PHP side - and I think its the PHP that has a limit? Am i wrong? I can fine grab what I need through the mysql console.

I run on a own and fast server, so this should really not be a problem - but I dont know which variables to configure (php settings)

```
My memory_limit is currently 128M
My max_execution_time is currently 800
```

What can I do?

Update:

The log says:
PHP Fatal error:  `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted`

Comment: Anything in the logs?

Comment: Nothing in the logs and i have tried error_reporting, nothing.

Comment: I suspect you've hit PHP's memory limit - although I'm a little surprised it's set so low!?!

Comment: Fetching the whole result set as array is likely the problem, it's either a timeout or memory exhaustion. You should loop through the result set row by row, getting only a row at a time from MySQL and outputting it without trying to cram it all into memory at once.

Comment: I just saw the log says PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

Comment: Does this help? <?php $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false); ?>

Comment: @deceze can you, as an answer, show me example of how you would do it without putting it all into memory at once ? Would you really do request for each row in the table ? 190k query requests ?

Comment: I have no idea how one would to this in Kohana, never worked with it. And no, not one request for each row. Fetching a result row from MySQL means you transfer the data for the result row from MySQL into PHP's memory. Currently you're trying to do this at once for all rows, but you can do it little by little as well.

Comment: @deceze no need for kohana, just mysql or whatever you like, just need to understand your logic

Comment: On a side note, why would one load 190 000 rows into a PHP script for stat extrapolation if there are functions that allow you to do so on MySQL end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP reached memory limit and that's normal with such great amount of data. You have to rethink your idea and try to load it in parts, calculate stats from them and then join it.
To do it you can load, lets say, 1000-5000 rows, calculate your stats, save into some variable/array and then load next part.

Other way is to increase memory limit, but it's not so good idea because it can be unstable.

Also it's good to try calculate stats in database directly, maybe it's possible? It'll be fastest way because database is prepared to operate on its data.

Comment: Storing to an array, will still consume memory limt according to @deceze, and i have also just tried your method which also says shows that it still consumes too much memory limit

Comment: @Karem Don't store rows! Calculate stats and save it, then remove used rows to release memory.

Answer (score 1):

Putting Kohana aside, because I have never used it, what you're currently doing is basically this:

```
$result = mysql_query(...);
$data   = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

I.e. you're getting all the data from MySQL with `mysql_fetch_assoc` and store them all in PHP's memory by pushing it into `$data`. That means PHP needs to have enough memory to store all data at once, which it hasn't.

What you want to do is fetch one result row from MySQL, do something with it, then move on to the next row without storing everything in memory at once:

```
$result = mysql_query(...);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['foo'];
}
```

And no, please don't use the deprecated mysql_ API, it's just the largest common denominator example here. Also, there must be a better way to do whatever you want to do than trying to fetch and output 190,000 rows at once.

Answer (score 0):

"Allowed memory size of **134217728 bytes exhausted**" => These are your configured **128 MB**. So you could increase the memory limit in the server's configuration / php.ini:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit

If you set this value to `-1` your scripts won't have any limit any more and can consume the entire available memory as far as the operating system allows this.

But it might be wise to either have the RDBMS do the calculation (without fetching all the stuff in php!) or do it in "packets", e.g. calculate the stats month by month seperately and then aggregate the month stats. This will cause less data to be loaded at once.

MySQL allows you to run several aggregate functions on your data. For example, you can have it calculate the average, the min/max value, the sum of all values, ... In this case you just SELECT the result and don't need to fetch all the data into your php script's memory to analyze it. Only for sophisticated statistics calculations the aggregate functions of MySQL aren't enough.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html